# Is there a way to sort row values by character length within a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, character

This is an example of a larger dataframe I have containing only characters.

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("00094", "00002", "00005", "00006", "00009", 
"00010", "00012", "00013", "00015", "00017"), V2 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, "2021-05-03", "2021-04-28", "Mentioned in T4 CRF", NA, "2022-10-10", 
"Mentioned in B1 CRF", "2022-07-14 w/ PCR-test"), V3 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "2022-07-12", "Antigen test, T4 CRF", NA, NA, NA, 
NA), V4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "2022-06-15", "2022-02-28", NA, NA, 
NA, NA), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Mentioned in B0 CRF", NA, 
NA, NA, NA), V6 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_), V7 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

is there any way to order each row by the length of each character in a row? In row 6 for example (where V1 = 00010), I would like V1 to stay the first column (it also has the lowest number of characters in the row), followed by V4 (nchar = 10), followed by V2 and V5 (nchar = 19) and then finally V3 (nchar = 20). Is there a way to do this?

Is it also possible to sort the strings that have nchar=10, which is essentially a date from old to new? - I can figure out a way to do this after the rows have been sorted but if there might be a way to do this while simultaneously ordering the rows based on character length, that'd be great

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to sort each row in orders of `nchar(x)` and `x` itself (in lexicographic order). Notice that in the 5th row of the output, `2022-06-15` has been moved to front of `2022-07-12`.

```r
as.data.frame(t(apply(df1, 1, \(x) x[order(nchar(x), x)])))

      V1                     V2                  V3                  V4                   V5   V6   V7
1  00094                   <NA>                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  00002                   <NA>                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
3  00005                   <NA>                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
4  00006             2021-05-03                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
5  00009             2021-04-28          2022-06-15          2022-07-12                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
6  00010             2022-02-28 Mentioned in B0 CRF Mentioned in T4 CRF Antigen test, T4 CRF <NA> <NA>
7  00012                   <NA>                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
8  00013             2022-10-10                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
9  00015    Mentioned in B1 CRF                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
10 00017 2022-07-14 w/ PCR-test                <NA>                <NA>                 <NA> <NA> <NA>
```